# SVN Checkout Within a Checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I seem to remember seeing this somewhere, but for the life of me search is not turning up the results I'm looking for.  Here's what I want:

I have a project repository.  There are libraries in other svn repositories that I'd like to include within my project.  When I do an SVN commit on the master project, I'd like all of the files, including the checkout of the libraries to be committed up to the master project repository.  At the same time, I'd also like to be able to do svn updates on just the library folder, and have it pull down updates from it's own repository elsewhere.

This is possible, right -- How?

In case that was a confusing description, I'll try to do a visual:

```
\ Project Repository  (@ my.svn.com )
    \ project source files
    \ project media files, etc.
    \ Libraries
        \ some library (@ gnu.svn.com )
        \ some other library (@ fsf.svn.com )
```

In this case, doing an SVN commit on the project itself will cause the contents of "some library" and "some other library" to be committed to the repository for "Project Repository".  However, if I were to do an SVN update on "some library", it would pull down it's updates from it's own svn, gnu.svn.com.

(currently using TortoiseSVN but not afraid to use command line svn if required)

Comment: Not that I am saying it is wrong to do so but why do you need to have the source code of all the libraries as opposed to just having the jar file for said library ? It seems to me like an overly complicated way to handle dependencies.  Again, I am not criticizing the choice but just curious on the specific use case that motivates it (SVN external vs lib folder with jar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking of [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html), my experience with them is from a long time ago but I found them to be painful to set up.

Comment: Ka-bam!  That was it.  As much a pain as it might be, I think I'll give it a shot because copying and pasting SVN checkouts of the libraries is getting old.

Comment: Last time I looked, SVN would not recurse into externally checked out folders for commits. Has that changed?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want *svn:externals*, which model the functionality that you are describing. See here: [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.htm](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)

Comment: Jinx, you can't speak until I say your name.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be thorough, TortoiseSVN does support setting SVN externals with a GUI interface.  Two references links:

http://justaddwater.dk/2007/10/23/setting-up-subversion-externals-with-tortoisesvn/

http://e-mats.org/2008/05/adding-an-external-svn-resource-with-tortoise/

(And it's not as bad as it might seem!)